# How do I insert Goal per day in Google Fit

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

Currently, I am sending activity and sleep data of my app to Google Fit.
And it is normal operation.
I want to send Today Goal(Goal steps or Goal minutes) from my app also.
I searched all Google Fit api. But I don't have any solution.
If you have solution, please let me know.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not yet possible. In the [**`Fitness`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/Fitness) Class:

> Google Fit supports different intents in order to help fitness apps collaborate. To that effect, different intent actions are defined in this class:
>
> - [**`ACTION_VIEW_GOAL`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/Fitness.html#ACTION_VIEW_GOAL) defines an intent to view a fitness goal.

Comment: Thank you~ I can not share my Goal with Google Fit. I wrote my goal step by using custom data api.